# How do I disable the opening and closing animation of the DropDown of a ComboBox in WPF?

Tags: wpf, animation, combobox, drop-down-menu

When I put a combobox in my WPF app, at runtime, when I click it, it rolls down the included items. After selection, it rolls the DropDown up again.

Is it possible to prevent the rolling animation from happening? Instead I'ld like to just have it open and closed immediately.

-
Marc

Comment: What OS are you running? I'm running XP and this does not occur using WPF's ComboBox control.

Comment: It happens for me on Vista and Win7. I'm not sure about XP. But I already realized that a few things are different between WPF on XP and WPF on Vista. For example the font smoothing looks differently.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible to simply disable the animation on the ComboBox as it stands. However, I believe the default ControlTemplate for the ComboBox implements the dropdown portion as a Popup. I'm guessing that it's using the `Slide` PopupAnimation setting. If you're up for it, you can replace the ControlTemplate for the ComboBox and set the PopupAnimation on that Popup to `None` or whatever setting you'd like.

Here's an example [ComboBox ControlTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752094.aspx) thanks to Microsoft.

Let me know if you need further assistance.

--
HTH,
Dusty

Answer (score 1):

You can also create a [custom ComboBox ala this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825845/wpf-combobox-dropdown-placement); so you'd end up with something like this.

```
class ComboBoxNoAnimation : ComboBox
{
    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();

        var popup = (Popup)Template.FindName("PART_Popup", this);            
        popup.PopupAnimation = PopupAnimation.None;
    }
}
```