# WPF ComboBox popup placement : Bottom and aligned to the right edge

Tags: wpf, drop-down-menu, combobox

I'm trying to create a `ComboBox` with a non-standard dropdown alignment. Basically, I want the dropdown to be below the `ComboBox`, but aligned with the right edge of the `ComboBox` instead of the left edge.

What a normal `ComboBox` looks like, using `PlacementMode="Bottom"`:

[image: combo box aligned to the left]

What I want:

[image: combobox aligned to the right]

I tried to play with the `Popup.PlacementMode` property in the template of my `ComboBox`, but none of the possible values seem to do what I want. Is there a simple way to do it, preferably in pure XAML?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

When I opened Expression Blend, I have come up with the solution within a few seconds:

```
<Popup Placement="Left" VerticalOffset="{TemplateBinding ActualHeight}" 
       HorizontalOffset="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}"
```

Sometimes this application is more useful than writing xaml by hands, but not so often.
[image]

Comment: This doesn't do what I'm asking at all... look at the images in my question

Comment: @Thomas Levesque Ok, I've attached the screenshot of my applciation. Sorry, but I can't see a difference between your second combobox and mine.

Comment: sorry, my mistake... I had missed the Placement="Left" part, it works perfectly now. Excellent answer, thanks!

Comment: Very elegant - however if you place en ComboBox on the right side of the Windows and maximize the Window **in a multi-monitor setup** where you have a monitor on the right hand side of the maximized window, the Popup will move to the monitor to the right :(

Comment: @kennethkryger Unfortunately I have only one monitor, so I can't imagine this problem and I don't know how this behavior differs from the default behavior. For some reason it seems to me that the left-aligned popup will have the same problems.

Comment: Very "elegant" way for breaking any automatic theming support of native controls.

Comment: @springy76 you should avoid sarcasm. You're not being constructive, so people will ignore you.

Answer (score 9):

I would use the "Custom" placementmode for the PopUp and declare a callback to place the popup control into the correct position, like it's shown here: [WPF ComboBox DropDown Placement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825845/wpf-combobox-dropdown-placement)

See if an example here would work for you:

```
public class TestComboBox : ComboBox
{
    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();

        var popup = (Popup)Template.FindName("PART_Popup", this);
        popup.Placement = PlacementMode.Custom;
        popup.CustomPopupPlacementCallback += (Size popupSize, Size targetSize, Point offset) => 
            new[] {  new CustomPopupPlacement() { Point = new Point (targetSize.Width-popupSize.Width, targetSize.Height) } };
    }
}
```

hope this helps, regards

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I thought of that too, but I prefer a pure XAML solution, and vorrtex's answer fits the bill perfectly

Comment: nice answer! easiest to implement

Answer (score 4):

Can someone post the complete xaml code please?

I've tried the following:

```
    <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Height="24" Width="20" HorizontalAlignment="Right"
              VerticalAlignment="Top"                  
              Name="comboBox2" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding  Source={StaticResource FilterTypes}}" 
              SelectedValue="{Binding Path=SelectedType, Mode=TwoWay}" >

        <ComboBox.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Popup Placement="Left" VerticalOffset="{TemplateBinding ActualHeight}" 
                        HorizontalOffset="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </ComboBox.Template>  
    </ComboBox>
```

... after some working and testing I've found a good solution...

```
        <ComboBox.Style>
            <Style TargetType="ComboBox" >                                    
                <Setter Property="Popup.FlowDirection" Value="RightToLeft"/>                  
            </Style>
        </ComboBox.Style>
```

Comment: just copy the original ComboBox template and modify only the Popup (you can find the original template in the [default themes](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/wpfsamples#themes))

Comment: @Sascha Krumbein Welcome to stackoverflow. This is not a forum. If you have a specific programming related question, please ask a new question.

Comment: This answer does not seem to add anything to the top-voted and accepted answer, it seems to be more of a question. Sascha, could you try improving the answer?

Answer (score 2):

it's a little hacky, but does work. you just have to change the combobox style.

```
    <Grid Height="40">
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <FrameworkElement Name="dummy" Visibility="Collapsed">
                <FrameworkElement.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup x:Name="xformgrp">
                        <TranslateTransform X="{Binding ElementName=PopupContent, Path=ActualWidth}" />
                        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="-1" />
                        <TranslateTransform X="{Binding ElementName=chk, Path=ActualWidth}" />
                    </TransformGroup>
                </FrameworkElement.RenderTransform>
            </FrameworkElement>
            <CheckBox Name="chk" HorizontalAlignment="Center">checkthisout</CheckBox>
            <Popup IsOpen="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=chk}" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=chk}" Placement="Bottom" HorizontalOffset="{Binding ElementName=dummy, Path=RenderTransform.Value.OffsetX}">
                <TextBlock Name="PopupContent" Foreground="Yellow" Background="Blue">yeah long popupcontent</TextBlock>
            </Popup>
        </Grid>            
    </Grid>
```

The popups HorizontalOffset just has to get the value of PopupContent.ActualWidth-PlacementTarget.ActualWidth. To get that value I used [this trick from Charles Petzold](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/08e73076-4d88-468b-a402-1e6c9429c5e1).

Comment: Thanks, very clever solution... but also quite scary ;)

Comment: @Thomas if you think that's scary.... Just kidding, you said, you didn't want any code behind. If you allow code-behind, just create a MultiBinding with a Converter that does PopupContent.ActualWidth-PlacementTarget.ActualWidth. That way your xaml doesn't look so scary, as the wohle dummy element gets eliminated.

Comment: a converter doesn't count as code-behind ;). Anyway, I wanted the simplest possible solution, and vorrtex's answer is by far the simplest and is pure XAML, so I accepted it