# WPF Align contextmenu to the right-bottom corner of the button

Tags: wpf, alignment, contextmenu

I have a Button and a `ContextMenu` that belongs to the `Button`.
Here is the xaml:

```
<Button x:Name="ListBoxButton" Content="6" Style="{DynamicResource TabControlButton}">
    <Button.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="tst1"></MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="tst2"></MenuItem>
        </ContextMenu>
    </Button.ContextMenu>
</Button>
```

I want to align my ContextMenu exactly the same place like image #2 [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5340640/wpf-combobox-popup-placement-bottom-and-aligned-to-the-right-edge)
**I want to use xaml to achieve it instead of code-behind.**

I couldnt achieve it, I tried to play with the `PlacementTarget`, `HorizontalOffset`, `VeritcalOffset` and `Placement` properties of the `ContextMenu` but it didnt aligned as I want..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you should try something like this

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Button HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                Height="20" Width="80" 
                ContextMenuService.Placement="Left"                     
                ContextMenuService.HorizontalOffset="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=ActualWidth}" 
                ContextMenuService.VerticalOffset="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=ActualHeight}">
            <Button.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <MenuItem Header="Menu item 01"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Menu item 02"/>
                </ContextMenu>
            </Button.ContextMenu>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```