# How to align the context menu to bottom right?

Tags: c#, wpf, alignment, contextmenu

I have the below code which I use to open the context menu of a `Rectangle`:

```
private void RectBtn_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var cm = ContextMenuService.GetContextMenu(sender as DependencyObject);
    if (cm == null)
        return;
    else
    {
        cm.Placement = PlacementMode.Top;
        cm.PlacementTarget = sender as UIElement;
        cm.IsOpen = true;
    }
}
```

So, my context menu, when appeared, looks as follows:

[image: Model 1]

Is there a way to achieve the below look from code behind (keeping the above code)?

[image: Model 2]

I looked at the solution on [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19674228/wpf-align-contextmenu-to-the-right-bottom-corner-of-the-button), but I need to achieve it from code behind. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This might help you get going: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750577(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 3):

Your code doesn't correspond to the images you posted. You set the `Bottom` placement, but on the screenshots, the context menu is positioned at the top of the target.

Anyway, you can use the `Custom` placement and calculate the position manually:

```
else
{
    cm.Placement = PlacementMode.Custom;
    cm.PlacementTarget = sender as UIElement;

    cm.CustomPopupPlacementCallback = 
        (popupSize, targetSize, offset) => 
            new[] 
            { 
                new CustomPopupPlacement 
                { 
                    Point = new Point(targetSize.Width - popupSize.Width, targetSize.Height) 
                } 
            };
          
    cm.IsOpen = true;
}
```

Comment: I edited my code....I will try your code aswell...But one last question....For example, i have 4 controls(i.e. Rectangle) side by side, each having the same height and width.. Is there a way that their contextmenu will appear in a certain area? I mean, suppose, a grid'w width is 400, now, at the bottom of it, i add 4 rects having 100px Width...So, is there a way, that all of their context menu will appear above them but will be stuck inside the grid/grid area? [sample image](https://imgur.com/a/JNkB3ld)

Comment: @zackraiyan, this is a different question. Please ask it separately.

Comment: Why ? The topic is the same....Do you know the answer or atleast give me some clues or some basic ideas?

Comment: @zackraiyan, because of [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts).