# how to make a wpf combobox popup Left

Tags: wpf, combobox, popup

I have a combo box with items wider than the actual combo box width, the drop down spills to the right.
How can we make a combo box popup up spills the left rather than the right side.

The FlowDirection doesn't do it.

The solution suggested in the the thread recommended would make the arrow of the the combo box on the left. I need it to stay on the right.

```
<ComboBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox" >                                    
            <Setter Property="Popup.FlowDirection" Value="RightToLeft"/>                  
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.Style>
```

Comment: This thread might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5340640/wpf-combobox-popup-placement-bottom-and-aligned-to-the-right-edge

Comment: I have came across this thread when I was searching but it does not achieve what I'm looking for.

Comment: It's a bit missleading saying that my proposed solution didn't change the behaviour. It did fullfill your initial requirements (changing the FlowDirection from LTR to RTL). 
If you wish for the arrow to be on the right side I'd suggest you consider looking at changing the render template or opening up a new thread question with the new requirements. Also don't bump by adding comments...

Comment: geostoker: If you read the solution (thread) recommended it shows the arrow on the right, but it actually makes it on the left. Don't take comments personal. Stay professional !

Comment: I'm not taking it personally at all, but it's not good SO format to keep adding requirements to a question as I've been told multiple times.
OT: There is no picture or mention of the arrow being on the opposite (right) side in the thread. However there is a known issue with the popup.placement if you have dual monitors according to the comments.
As mentioned, have a look at how to manipulate the renderer (this is mentioned on other threads). :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to extend the standard `ComboBox` control in order to manipulate its `Popup` control. In my opinion this is the easiest and fastest solution for your issue.

```
public class LeftComboBox : ComboBox
{
    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();

        Popup popup = GetTemplateChild("PART_Popup") as Popup;
        popup.Placement = PlacementMode.Custom;
        popup.CustomPopupPlacementCallback = new CustomPopupPlacementCallback(CustomPopupPlacementCallback);
    }

    private static CustomPopupPlacement[] CustomPopupPlacementCallback(Size popupSize,
        Size targetSize, Point offset)
    {
        Point point = new Point(targetSize.Width - popupSize.Width, targetSize.Height);

        List<CustomPopupPlacement> customPopupPlacement =
            new List<CustomPopupPlacement>();

        customPopupPlacement.Add(new CustomPopupPlacement(point, PopupPrimaryAxis.Vertical));

        return customPopupPlacement.ToArray();
    }
}
```

By extending the standard `ComboBox` control you can override the `OnApplyTemplate` and you can force its `Popup` to use the custom `PlacementMode`.

Then you can write your own [CustomPopupPlacementCallback](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.custompopupplacementcallback(v=vs.110).aspx). Mine just changes the `Popup` horizontal offset, moving it towards left.

I hope it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest doing that with Behavior.I'm adding example with MenuItem but it the same for any control with PopUp (like ComboBox)

On your Xaml add the attach behavior to the menu item:

```
      <Menu>
            <MenuItem ItemsSource="{Binding GlanceOptions, Mode=OneWay}">

                <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <behaviors:MenueItemSubMenuPlacementBehavior />
                </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>

                <MenuItem.Header>
                    <Border                    
                        Cursor="Arrow"
                        BorderThickness="1,1,1,0" >
                        <Path x:Name="DropDownIcon"
                                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                        Data="M0,0L2,3 4,0z"
                                        />
                    </Border>
                </MenuItem.Header>
            </MenuItem >
        </Menu>
```

The behavior Code:

```
        public class MenueItemSubMenuPlacementBehavior : Behavior<MenuItem>
        {
            private PlacementMode _previousPlacementMode;
            private CustomPopupPlacementCallback _previousCallback;
            private Popup _menuItemPopUp;

            protected override void OnAttached()
            {
                base.OnAttached();

                Initialize();
            }

            private void Initialize()
            {
                if (AssociatedObject == null)
                    return;

                if (_menuItemPopUp == null)
                {
                    _menuItemPopUp = AssociatedObject?.Template?.FindName("PART_Popup", AssociatedObject) as Popup;

                    if (_menuItemPopUp == null)
                    {
                        AssociatedObject.Loaded -= AssociatedObject_Loaded;
                        AssociatedObject.Loaded += AssociatedObject_Loaded;
                        return;
                    }

                    _previousPlacementMode = _menuItemPopUp.Placement;
                    _previousCallback = _menuItemPopUp.CustomPopupPlacementCallback;

                    _menuItemPopUp.Placement = PlacementMode.Custom;
                    _menuItemPopUp.CustomPopupPlacementCallback = CustomPopupPlacementCallback;
                }
            }

            private void AssociatedObject_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                AssociatedObject.Loaded -= AssociatedObject_Loaded;

                if (_menuItemPopUp != null)
                    return;

                _menuItemPopUp = VisualTreeHelpers.FindFirstChild<Popup>(AssociatedObject) as Popup;

                if (_menuItemPopUp == null)
                    return;

                _previousPlacementMode = _menuItemPopUp.Placement;
                _previousCallback = _menuItemPopUp.CustomPopupPlacementCallback;

                _menuItemPopUp.Placement = PlacementMode.Custom;
                _menuItemPopUp.CustomPopupPlacementCallback = CustomPopupPlacementCallback;
            }

            protected override void OnDetaching()
            {
                base.OnDetaching();

                if(AssociatedObject != null)
                {
                    AssociatedObject.Loaded -= AssociatedObject_Loaded;
                }

                if (_menuItemPopUp != null)
                {
                    _menuItemPopUp.Placement = _previousPlacementMode;
                    _menuItemPopUp.CustomPopupPlacementCallback = _previousCallback;

                    _previousCallback = null;
                }
            }

            private CustomPopupPlacement[] CustomPopupPlacementCallback(Size popupSize, Size targetSize, Point offset)
            {
                var rightPlacedPopupX = offset.X;
                var rightPlacedPopupY = offset.Y + (AssociatedObject.ActualHeight * YourLogic);

                return new[]
                {
                    new CustomPopupPlacement(new Point(rightPlacedPopupX, rightPlacedPopupY), PopupPrimaryAxis.Horizontal),
                };
            }
        }
```